# Rotating green marker in MyLocationNewOverlay

Tags: android, osmdroid

I recently changed MyLocationOverlay to MyLocationNewOverlay in my project, due to MyLocationOverlay being deprecated now.

My problem is when I used MyLocationOverlay, the green arrow marker when you are moving was always pointing in the same direction as the compass, but with MyLocationNewOverlay it doesn't do that anymore.

Is it a removed feature in MyLocationNewOverlay or is there a new way to make it cooperate with CompassOverlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's better later than never!

I found that the reason I wasn't satisfied with the behaviour is because my hardware was kind of de-synced and made the green marker point in wrong directions.

The behaviour it had in MyLocationOverlay made it synced with compass, but that changed in MyLocationNewOverlay which makes it point in the direction you're moving towards based on your GPS location and other data (mine was not properly sync and made it point in random directions.)

In the end, there was no problem with the marker and this is the intended new behaviour which makes more sense than syncing to the compass.